# Como independizar las funciones de ajax ya que son llamadas por selects dinamicos creados mediante clone

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, clone

Tengo un form con tres grupos inputs, los primeros son fijo, los segundos son generados dinamicamente mediante .clone y los terceros son fijos. El problema es el segundo grupo de inputs tengo dos select el primero es llenado mediante consulta ajax al seleccionar este llena el segundo select igual mediante ajax y al seleccionar este ultimo select llena tres campos inputs en la misma consulta ajax; al agregar otra fila de inputs las funciones ajax no funcionan correctamente no son independientes de cada fila.

codigo split_ticket.js

```
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone(true)
        .appendTo("div.clonar")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
        }
    })
    .on('click', 'a.remove', remove);
cloneIndex++;

}
function remove(){

    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("a.clone").on("click", clone);

$("a.remove").on("click", remove);
```

codigo html del form

```
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
                Grower</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                <select id="tkt_grower0" class="form-control tkt_grower" 
name="tkt_grower[]" >
                    <option value="">Select grower</option>
                  <?php foreach ($all_growers as $grower ):
                   echo '<option 
value="'.$grower['gwh_id'].'">'.ucwords($grower['gwh_name']).'</option>';
                    endforeach;?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
                Stack</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>
                <select id="tkt_stack0" class="form-control tkt_stack"     name="tkt_stack[]" >
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
                Commodity</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <input id="tkt_commodity0" name="tkt_commodity[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control tkt_commodity" readonly/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
            Barn</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                <select id="tkt_barn0" class="form-control tkt_barn" name="tkt_barn[]">';
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
            Bales</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
                <input id="tkt_bales0" name="tkt_bales[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control tkt_bales" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
            Bales in Field</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                <input id="chd_balescount0" name="chd_balescount[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control chd_balescount" readonly/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUsername" class="control-label">
            Name Location Hay</label>
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>
                <input id="chd_haylocation0" name="chd_haylocation[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control chd_haylocation" readonly/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMore" class="control-label">
            Split</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <a class="btn btn-primary clone"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> More Lots</a> 
                <a class="btn btn-primary remove"><i class="fa fa-minus">    </i> Remove Lots</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="clonar" class="clonar">
</div>
```

funciones ajax para llenar los select

```
function carga_stack(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'select_stack.php?module=find_stack',
        data: 'id='+val,
        success: function(resp){
            $('.tkt_stack').html(resp);
        }
    });
}

function carga_lote(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'select_stack.php?module=find_lot',
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'id='+val,
        success: function(resp){
            $(".tkt_commodity").val(resp.chd_croptype);
            $(".chd_balescount").val(resp.chd_balescount);
            $(".chd_haylocation").val(resp.chd_haylocation);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: En donde llamas a las funciones ajax?

Comment: `<select id="tkt_grower0" class="form-control tkt_grower" 
name="tkt_grower[]"  onchange="carga_stack(this.value);">`

  **  y en **


    `<select id="tkt_stack0" class="form-control tkt_stack"     name="tkt_stack[]" >  onchange="carga_lote(this.value);" </select>`

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de pasar el valor, pasa el objeto asi:

```
<select id="tkt_grower0" class="form-control tkt_grower" name="tkt_grower[]" onchange="carga_stack(this);">
```

Luego en las funciones ajax, recuperas el valor y usas el elemento como selector asi:

```
function carga_stack(select) {

    var val = $(select).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'select_stack.php?module=find_stack',
        data: 'id='+val,
        success: function(resp){
            $(select').html(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: me arroja este error en la consola `Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined` y me elimina el contenido del primer select